# Nginx rewriting the Ghost Blog URL

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Let's say, I have ghost blog installed at `http://shawn.arthur.io/`.
Rather than creating multiple blogs, I made a single blog and exploited the "tag" usage to separate different collections.

```
> http://shawn.arthur.io/en/tag/travel
> http://shawn.arthur.io/en/tag/culture
> http://shawn.arthur.io/en/tag/food
```

I find it nearly impossible to modify the ghost backend. Can I add a rewrite rule in the nginx ghost configuration file which would be show content of `http://shawn.arthur.io/en/tag/$X` when actually you visit `http://shawn.arthur.io/en/blogs/$X`

Following is my nginx code:

```
        location /en {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:2368;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_buffering off;
        }

    location /en/blogs {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:2368/en/tag;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_buffering on;
    }
```

**PROBLEM**

When I write, http://shawn.arthur.io/en/blogs/sklfasjfask, it works fine, but when I come to the webpage through a link, it automatically redirects to http://shawn.arthur.io/en/tag/sklfasjfask. Why does this happen? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You could effectively mask the `/en/tag` prefix by adding another `location` block containing a `rewrite` statement. For example:

```
location /en/tag {
    rewrite ^/en/tag(.*)$ /en/blogs$1 permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd let Ghost do this for you.
https://docs.ghost.org/tutorials/implementing-redirects/

Note, I just realized I am responding in 2019 and you asked this in 2017. Maybe Ghost didn't have this functionality built in at that time. I am answering regardless in case my response helps another person.